# How can I highlight text in latex

Tags: latex

How can i highlit text in `latex`.
Thank you.

As is pictured here(in red circle):
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This links look useful:

- [Insert symbols inside verbatim mode LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150965/insert-symbols-inside-verbatim-mode-latex)
- [Putting math inside a verbatim environment without altering the formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125190/putting-math-inside-a-verbatim-environment-without-altering-the-formatting)

If you just wanted `graph.exe` I would suggest using `\begin{verbatim} graph.exe \end{verbatim}` or `\verb+graph.exe+` .

However you want to use the `<..>` expression which can be created with `$ \langle ... \rangle $` . The `$..$` indicates inline math mode. Those two links discuss getting verbatim text in math environments.

I think [tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) will be more helpful rather than stack overflow.

Comment: This does not seem to be about highlighting but different formatting.

Answer (score 10):

If you mean making the text bold by Highlighting you can use  `\textbf` for making the text bold but highlighting has a different general meaning that is implemented by `\hl` keyword.

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{color} % for the command \textcolor
\usepackage{soul} % for the command \hl
\begin{document}
  \hl{foo}
  \hl{\textbf{foo}} 
  {my garden }
  \textbf{black}{foo}
  {my good job}
  \textbf{\textcolor{red}{\hl{foo}}}
  \textcolor{red}{\textbf{\hl{foo}}}
\end{document}
```

this is the result :

[image]

As you can see the word "black" is highlighted the way you desired.

The word "foo" is highlighted in the general meaning of highlighting.

Comment: This could be a ressource for that: https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/latex/highlight-text-in-latex-document/

Comment: The answer should indicate which package `\hl` comes from. i.e. from `color` or from `soul`?

Comment: For anyone else landing here in the future, the soul package is here: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/soul

Comment: Critical detail from the `soul` docs: "The \hl command does only highlight if the color package was loaded, otherwise
it falls back to underlining."